# Printing 2-D array through pointers

Tags: c

My teacher gave me a problem to solve in which: -

> 1) User will input "n" number of triangles.
>
> 2) After inputting "n", The user will input the sides of triangles.
>
> 3) We basically have to print those sides (Basically a question of 2-D
>   arrays).

This is my implementation of the problem: -

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{
    int number_of_triangles; // Takes the value of number of triangles the user will input.
    scanf("%d", &number_of_triangles);

    int *array;
    array = malloc(number_of_triangles * 3 * sizeof(int)); 
//trying to create a 2D array whose column size is fixed i.e. 3.


    int i,j; // Counter variables.

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_triangles; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", ((array + i) + j)); // Scanning value of sides of triangle.
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_triangles; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", (*(array + i) + j));//printing those sides. <-This is the problem statement.
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine but I have a doubt in this line given below: -

```
for(i = 0; i < number_of_triangles; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", (*(array + i) + j));
//printing those sides. <-This is the problem statement.
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Should it not be `printf("%d ", *(*(array + i) + j))`  instead of `printf("%d ", (*(array + i) + j))` to get the values of the sides of triangle?

If I put `printf("%d ", *(*(array + i) + j))` then I get error:-

> Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid).

What I have learned in C is that in order to dereference a 2-D array pointer we have to use the former method instead of latter which I have used in my code. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `*(array + i) + j` is equal to `(*(array + i)) + j`.

Comment: Also, remember that for any pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter is much easier to understand and read, and less to write as well.

Comment: Also, `array + i + j` is *wrong* and will not give you the pointers you want. I suggest you take some pen and paper and draw your "array" on the paper and do the arithmetic to see how wrong it is.

Comment: Shouldn't `*((array + i) + j))` work then? Is `*((array + i) + j)) == (*(array + i) + j))` ?

Comment: No, `*((array + i) + j))` is *not* the same as `(*(array + i) + j))`. Think about it for a while... `*(array + i)` is equal to `array[i]` which is a single element in the "array", of type `int`. Then you add `j` making it the same as `array[i] + j`.

Comment: So `*((array + i) + j) == array[i + j]` @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Yes that's correct. Unfortunately your index calculation is wrong. Think about when e.g. `i == 0` and `j == 1`, followed by `i == 1` and `j == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dereference twice. You're dealing with a 1D array, that you're using as a 2D one.

`array + i` has type `int *`, so `*(array + i)` has type `int`, which you can't dereference again.

Instead, you want to use `i` and `j` to get the correct index. The index you want is `i * 3 + j`:

```
*(array + i * 3 + j)
```

It's however much prettier to use the `[]` notation, which is equivalent:

```
array[i * 3 + j]
```

---

`*(*(array + i) + j))` could be used when you have a 2D array constructed by having an array of pointers to arrays, or when the type used is a multidimensional array.

For example:

```
int **array;
array = malloc(number_of_triangles * sizeof(int *)); 

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_triangles; ++i)
    array[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_triangles; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        printf("array[%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, *(*(array + i) + j)));
```

(I've left out all checks for success of allocation. These must be included if this code was being used.)

Note that the last line of the example is *very* ugly. `*(*(array + i) + j))` is equivalent to `array[i][j]`. It could therefore be rewritten:

```
        printf("array[%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
```

Another use of the double-dereference is with multidimensional array types.

For example, if you know ahead of time the number of triangles:

```
int array[5][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        printf("array[%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, *(*(array + i) + j)));
```

In this case, we take advantage of the fact that array identifiers decay to pointers to their first element. `array + i` is a pointer to the `i`th triangle, so `*(array + i)` is an lvalue of type `int *` pointing to the array 3 of `int` for the triangle `i`.

`*(array + i) + j` is an `int *` pointing to the side `j` of triangle `i`, so `*(*(array + i) + j))` is an lvalue of type `int` for that element.

Again, it's much prettier to use array notation, replacing `*(*(array + i) + j))` with `array[i][j]`.

Comment: Then when we use `*(*(array + i) + j))` ?

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla You'd use that when you have an array of pointers to array. I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you did not allocate a two-dimensional array. You allocated a one dimensional array with `3 * number_of_triangles`  elements.

The program is invalid because in this loop

```
for(i = 0; i < number_of_triangles; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", ((array + i) + j)); // Scanning value of sides of triangle.
    }
}
```

you are overwriting already inputted values.

This expression

```
((array + i) + j)
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
array + ( i + j)
```

So `array + ( 0 + 1 )` is equal to `array + ( 1 + 0 )` That is if to use indices then the both expression are equivalent to `&array[1]`

if your compiler supports variable length arrays then the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_triangles; // Takes the value of number of triangles the user will input.
    scanf("%d", &number_of_triangles);

    int ( *array )[3] = malloc( sizeof( int[number_of_triangles][3] ) );

    for ( int ( *p )[3] = array; p != array + number_of_triangles; ++p )
    {
        for( int *q = *p; q != *p + 3; ++q )
        {
            scanf( "%d",  q ); // Scanning value of sides of triangle.
        }
    }


    for ( int ( *p )[3] = array; p != array + number_of_triangles; ++p )
    {
        for( int *q = *p; q != *p + 3; ++q )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *q );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( array );

    return 0;
}
```

You can the loops also rewrite like

```
for ( int i = 0; i < number_of_triangles; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    {
        scanf( "%d",  *( array + i ) + j ); // Scanning value of sides of triangle.
    }
}


for ( int i = 0; i < number_of_triangles; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *( *( array + i ) + j ) );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Otherwise you have to allocate a one dimensional array of pointers to one dimensional integer arrays.

Comment: You are correct. Just inputted another set of different values using my code and the output was garbage. Thank you for your answer.